# Linux Program Source Management

Tags: linux, version-control, source

This particular problem has little do with SubVersion Repositories and more to do with the management of installed programs. My question revolves around the problem of installing a program from source. If I where to build a distro with no package management system what possibilities would I have for maintaining the program is up to date. My only idea would be to keep a record of all the programs installed from source and perform a periodic check to identify if a new version is out.

Comment: Yep, that's basically it.

Answer (score 0):

You've pretty much nailed it. Manual tracking of version's installed and version releases is the only way to do it without a built package-management system of some kind. Not all binaries do "-V" for version, or even have any way of getting version information, so you have to note that down when you install it.

And then there is tracking all the release sites for new versions.

And then chasing down the dependencies.

Not fun. Doable manually, and a lot of work. But it can be done.